# PHP Session variable changing from page to page

Tags: php

I'm using a session variable to save the last page the user visited in the search results so that they can go back to that page.

if I make

```
echo($_SESSION['page'])
```

at he end of the results pages the value is correct, but when I reload the page (or load any other page) the value is increased by 1. I made a `echo($_SESSION['page'])` right after the `session_start()` call and it was already increased, so I guess it's been increased right before the PHP code for the search results finishes running but can't find the line of code that is doing so.

In order to test this added a new variable called `$_SESSION['page2']` and this new variable is been increased too.

Any ideas?

EDIT

The variable is taking the value from a Pager object like this

```
$_SESSION['page'] = $pager->getCurrentPageID();
```

And I can't find any other place where its been set to a different value. We use the same unit and code in a different site and never had this problem before. Tried replacing the code and the Pager class definition with those from the other site and that didn't fix it.

Comment: In order to help you we'd need moar code.

Comment: can you share some code. I guess you are updating value somewhere.

Comment: First: check your access logs. Is there a single request, or is there a bug making the user request everything twice? The latter is the most common cause I've seen for problems like these.

Comment: Show us your code. The code which sets the session in the first place, and what file it is in ie include file which is included in all files (ie, a session wouldn't auto increment without something doing it)

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
```

Has to be called before anything is echoed to the browser, best practice is to have it as the first thing you have on your PHP page.

Giving you a better answers is no problem, if you provide more code.

[More about session_start();](http://www.php.net/session_start)